# R - read.table(), subsetting and converting data during import

Tags: r, import, subset, read.table

I have been trying to read a text file with data using read.table, but there are 3 issues I have to solve concurrently.

1. The data I am reading has a mix of different column classes.

Date ; Time ; numeric1 ; numeric2; numeric3 etc.

When I import the date and time are being imported as factors. I tried

```
    x <- read.table("file.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";", nrows = 10, colClasses = c("Date", "Time", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
```

but I get this error

```
    Error in methods::as(data[[i]], colClasses[i]) : no method or default for coercing “character” to “Time”
```

I dont want to read the whole file and subset and change the classes.

2. This text file has about 2 million records, but I want to read only 2016 and 2017 data, again dont want to subset.
3. I want to convert the time column into the time class

Is there a way I can do all of that at one shot during importing.. ?

Comment: time conversion from text files is always tricky.  I think it's best to import as strings and figure out how to convert into time once it's in memory, perhaps with the help of some useful date-processing package such as `lubridate`.  Can you show examples of the time formats?

Answer (score 0):

I read using fread from data.table but skip a few rows to get only 2017 and 2016 data. Unfortunately you will need to find this possibly interactively especially if data in not sorted.

From https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4/topics/fread

dt=fread(input, **skip="string"**,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dt

I refer to fasttime package for the date

dt[,Datevar := as.POSIXct(Datevar)]

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasttime/fasttime.pdf